# INDEX, MATCH - find first 2 instances of match and return the row above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to check a column for an exact name (in my pictured example, JonP and not JonF) and return the time that appears in the row above the name.  I have been able to figure out how to return the first instance by using this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$9,MATCH("*"&$D2&"*",A$2:A$9,0)-1,1),"")`

What I want to do is find both instances of JonP and then use TEXTJOIN to list the times that are above each instance of JohnP.

I've looked at the examples on the below 2 pages.

1. https://trumpexcel.com/lookup-second-value/
2. https://www.get-digital-help.com/index-match-multiple-results/
   [image: example]
   ...but my understanding of how the other functions (SMALL, ISNUMBER,ROW, COLUMN) are interacting in those examples is too tenuous for me to figure out how to apply it to my situation, which is different, since I'm only matching within in 1 column (vs between the 2 different columns in the examples) and want to return the value in the row above the match.

---EDIT---
Here is a picture of the final solution, after realizing I needed to account for instances in which the string I was searching for was mixed with other names. `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(Schedule[Schedule],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,OFFSET(Schedule[Schedule],1,0)))))`

[image: corrected example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(Schedules,DROP(VSTACK("",Table1[Schedule]),-1),
 TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(Schedules,Table1[Schedule]=C2)))
```

It first creates an offset of the schedule (down one).

Like that it could be used to filter the schedule-table.

If it helps for visualisation try this:

```
=LET(Schedules,DROP(VSTACK("",Table1[Schedule]),-1),
HSTACK(Table1[Schedule],Schedules))
```

[image]

----- EDIT ---
Solution w/o `VSTACK`

```vb
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(Table1[Schedule],OFFSET(Table1[Schedule],1,0)=C2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It worked, but unfortunately, it looks like only in Microsoft 365, since VSTACK/HSTACK functions are only available in that version.  I need to share this will people who don't have Microsoft 365 and it's returning a name error in the desktop version.

Comment: Yes - it's a Excel 365 solution, I thought you can use it as `TEXTJOIN` is also only available in Excel 365.

Comment: Got it.  'TEXTJOIN' also works in my desktop version (Professional Plus 2021).

Comment: Ok - I wasn't aware of that. It's getting complicated, which formulas are available in what version :-/

Comment: Added a solution using `OFFSET` instead of `VSTACK` - should work with Excel 2019

Comment: Thanks, Ike!  Your solution answered my original question but I then realized that I hadn't mentioned that sometimes the name/string I'm searching for is mixed with another name, so I needed to search for the name within the cell.  This is the modification to their solution that I came up with.  `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(Schedule[Schedule],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,OFFSET(Schedule[Schedule],1,0)))))`